# mysql not returning date value saved in database

Tags: mysql, datetime

I'm doing a simple select statement on my mysql database. The table contains two different date fields, `date_created`, and `last_modified`. Both columns are datetime datatypes.

When I view the data in the database, the values are all saved in the correct format, but for some reason, my resultset returned is changing the value of `date_created` to 2011-07-14 10:05:30 for every record, but the `last_modified` date is returning the correct value.

Is `date_created` a reserved word?

My SQL is:

```
SELECT `r`.*, `u`.* 
FROM `reports` AS `r` 
LEFT JOIN `users` AS `u` ON u.user_id = r.user_id 
WHERE (r.user_id = 4) 
ORDER BY 1 asc 
LIMIT 20
```

Not sure why this is only affecting one of the dates.

I'm using Zend Studio if that has anything to do with it?

Comment: Just a quickie: `date_created` is not a keyword, we all use it in tables.

Comment: Another quickie: why not `date_modified` instead of `last_modified`?

Comment: Thanks guys, i didn't think it was a keyword, but wanted to make sure. Also, i didn't create the database or get to name the fields :) although date_modified would be better, i don't think last_modified is terrible. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have `date_created` field in both tables. In this case, you will get only one of these in your PHP result array indexed by field name.

Comment: OMG, i think i need stronger coffee. i can't believe i didn't think of this. yes, that is the problem. Sometimes i hate the obvious :) Thanks!

Comment: Haha, i tried, but i had to wait 4 more minutes :) done now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

do you by any chance also have `date_created` column on `users` table?

maybe the value comes from there?

hard to answer as you didn't provide any code where you use results of your query.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `date_created` and `last_modified` columns in both tables? If that is the case, do you see `date_created` from both tables to be 2011-07-14 10:05:30?

```
SELECT `r`.*,
       `u`.*
FROM `reports` AS `r`
     LEFT JOIN `users` AS `u` ON u.user_id = r.user_id
WHERE (r.user_id = 4)
ORDER BY 1 asc
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Yes, i did. Thanks for responding. It's weird, i ran the SQL directly in mySql and it returned the correct date values, but when running from my project, it was using the user date_created value. Anyway, can't belive i didn't notice this... i'm a little embarrassed now, but it's working. Thanks again!